# convert any matrix to black and white picture

Tags: python

I'm new in pythin and I want to convert a square matrix to a square pixel.
I have a 5.*5 matrix whose numbers are totally random. like this:
a=[0 1 -1 5 -5
30 -30 22 -25 19
-15 7 -7 5 -4
3 -2 1 -1 0
-1 1 -1 1 0]

and I want to convert this matrix to 5.*5 black and white pictures by using python.
and I know that I should use NumPy.
could anyone tell me what should i do??
I want to that output pictures become sth like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FlJi.png)

Comment: Hey! A looks like a list of integers, not a matrix nor numpy array. Numbers doesn't look like a conventional image. What do you mean with "square pixel"? Your question is a little confusing. If trying to convert color image to grayscale, consider using openCV like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/converting-an-image-from-colour-to-grayscale-using-opencv).

Comment: thank you for your answering, look I have a 1024 continuous dataset and I want to convert these data to 32*32 pictures. as the MNIST has 28*28 pixel I want to create my own dataset with 32*32

Comment: What do you mean by "1024 continues dataset"? Which is the format? Can you share it? Or at least a smaller real example

Answer (score 0):

First you need a matrix, use `np.matrix()` for that.
Then, use `Image.fromarray()` from the PIL library

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

a = np.matrix([[0, 1, -1, 5, -5], [30, -30, 22, -25, 19], [-15, 7, -7, 5, -4], [3, -2, 1, -1, 0], [-1, 1, -1, 1, 0]])

a=(a - np.min(a)) / (np.max(a) - np.min(a))*255

img = Image.fromarray(a)
img.save('my.png')
img.show()
```

Comment: thank you,but when I run this code. a completely black picture appears. but I want something like Chess pictures with different colors(black, white, grey).

Comment: No, it doesn't, at least not for me ;) It provides a gray scale image, but negative values are mapped to 0 (black) so it's mostly black.  That is why I mentioned normalizing the matrix. But I added that line for you.

Comment: @milikia: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If yes, please remember to accept it. :)